# Legacy site 3.3.6 - upgrade issue

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm having an issue upgrading a quickstart package from 3.3.6 to 3.8. I initially tried a direct upgrade through the Joomla update component but this failed with a 500 error. I enabled error reporting and get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   JApplicationAdministrator::isClient() in
>   /home/mydomain/public_html/plugins/system/stats/stats.php on line 82

I then restored from backup and tried a 3.4 upgrade package and received the same error. I also tried uploading a 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 full package and extracting over the existing site but I still get the same error.

I renamed the stats folder and just got a blank white screen on the admin even though error reporting was enabled. I checked the error log and it reports:

> [27-Sep-2017 23:30:00 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  Call to
>   undefined method JApplicationAdministrator::isClient() in
>   /home/mydomain/public_html/plugins/quickicon/phpversioncheck/phpversioncheck.php
>   on line 204

So i renamed the phpversioncheck folder and could access the admin panel....brilliant, I'm now on J3.4

I next try an update to 3.5. I cannot update through the Ext installation method i.e. Extensions > Extension Manager > Install > Upload Package file ('m not sure what version of Joomla this became obsolete) and when I go to Components > Joomla Update > Options i get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method JApplicationAdministrator::isClient() in /home/mydomain/public_html/administrator/components/com_fields/models/fields.php on line 230

So..I then just try an update to 3.8 through the update component (what the hell) and get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   JApplicationAdministrator::isClient() in
>   /home/mydomain/public_html/plugins/system/logout/logout.php on line 48

Following this I start renaming folders as I get the errors such as:
stats (again) 
remember
redirect

I'm running out of idea's so If anyone has any idea's it would be most welcome :)

Thank you in advance.

Regards
D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delete your entire public_html folder and database and start again from the 3.3.6 site.  isClient() is a method of japplication that was introduced in Joomla 3.7.  As your first upgrade failed, you've got Joomla 3.8 code in random places including the database, and copying more legacy Joomla code over the top will just keep causing more chaos.

From 3.3.6, if it wont go straight to 3.8, then try 3.5.1 using method B as detailed here: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Upgrading_from_Joomla_3.4.x_to_3.5